# Cuda Native Provider - Missing MathNet.Numerics.CUDA.dll

Tags: math.net, mathnet-numerics

[Math.Net 3.7.0 Release Notes](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MathNet.Numerics/) on nuget mention a CUDA native provider.

```
Control.UseNativeCUDA();
```

throws a DllNotFoundException for MathNet.Numerics.CUDA.dll. For the MKL-provider i need to install an extra NuGet-Package. Is there no package for the CUDA.dll yet? Or what do i have to install?

I'm using MathNet on linux with mono.

Answer (score 2):

You are right. Currently there is no NuGet package available.
Also note that the CUDA support is not stable (alpha) yet.